# How to use the age_calc function with a "date of birth"column?

Tags: r

How can you use age_calc function in Rstudio to calculate the age of employees (in years), provided you have a large data set (more than 19 000 entries) where "Date of Birth " is a column name, and then add the ages as a new column to the data set?.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create reproducible example data

```
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:5,
                   Date_of_Birth = c("1999-03-05", "1999-05-19", "1999-07-01", "1999-02-27", "1999-06-11"))
```

2.Convert date string column to actual date using `as.Date`

```
data$Date_of_Birth <- as.Date(data$Date_of_Birth, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

3.Define `calc_age_days` function that takes dates as argument and returns the number of days since that date

```
calc_age_days <- function(date_value) {
  return(Sys.Date() - date_value)
}
```

4.Use `calc_age_days` function to calculate Age column

```
data$Age <- calc_age_days(date_value=data$Date_of_Birth)
```